# How to use the same button for different actions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need a button when clicked that shows a specific image. But when clicked again, needs to show a different image. The images shown are stored in an array in a sequence I want them to be shown in. 
I've used a function to change one picture to the next on the button click but when I try to change to the third image it skips the second one. How would I do this?
This is my code so far:

```
<img id="red" src="traffic-light-red.jpg">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="change"></p>
<script>

var lights= ["traffic-light-red.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg", "traffic-light-green.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg"]

var image = document.getElementById("red")

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("change");
    image.src = lights[1]
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try the following code to do the action you want. 
Keep a variable say "counter" outside the function.

On clicking on the button, get lights[counter] and set is as source of the img. Then increase the counter by 1.

When it reaches the length of the array, make the counter '0' again. So that it can start from the first image again.

```js
var counter = 0;

var lights= ["traffic-light-red.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg", "traffic-light-green.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg"]

var image = document.getElementById("red");

function myFunction()
{
  image.src = lights[counter];
  console.log(image.src);
  counter += 1;
  
  if(counter == lights.length)
    {
      counter = 0;
      }
}
```

```html
<img id="red" src="traffic-light-red.jpg">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="change"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

From your code above it seems you're always setting the index to 1 (`image.src = lights[1]`) which will always load the second image when you click the button. You should assign the current index of the image loaded to a variable and increment this.

[edited]
In my answer below selecting the image based in index which is intially set to zero for the first image, then incrementing the index. I'm also checking the value of index, if it's equal to the last element in the lights array, then I'm resetting it to zero, which will return you to the starting image.

As follows:

```
var lights= ["traffic-light-red.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg", "traffic-light-green.jpg", "traffic-light-amber.jpg"]
var index = 0;
var image = document.getElementById("red")

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("change");

    image.src = lights[index]
    index++;
    if(index >= lights.length) {
        index = 0;
    } 
}
```

Also be aware of arrays and array index. The array below will have a length of 5 but it's 5th item will have an index of 4. This is because the length property will return the number of items, but javascript (like most programming languages) starts counting from zero.

This is why I'm checking for greater than or equal to in my answer above `if(index >= lights.length)`, if the index is equal to 4 then it will look for the fifth element in the arrray, which doesn't exist. (I probably don't need the greater than tbh, but I think it's good practice to include it).

```
var arr = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"];
console.log(arr[0]) // item1 - First element, index 0
console.log(arr[4] // item5 - Fifth element, index 4
```

Comment: Your code in the function "myFunction()", will take the second item initially, instead of taking the first item. So first time clicking on the button will show the second image from the array. @Phill

Comment: So it will, didn't think that through. I've udpated, thanks @titi23.

Comment: Now the answer if right as per the requirement. @Phill

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
<button id="" onclick="lights()">Click me</button>
<img id="red" src="add file name">

<script>
function lights(){
    var sequence=[your files];
    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    var i = 0;
    intervalHandler = setInterval(function(){
    var colour=sequence[i]
    image.src = colour;
    i++;
    if(i>=sequence.length) {
        clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    }
    },1000)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
use hidden field to store current image and get increment value on each click

```
<input type="hidden" name="imageindex" id="imageindex" value="0">
```

On your function "myFunction()" create logic to get and increment the imageindex value. If value of imageindex is greater then your image array then reset to 0. Please get reference from following Javascript code.

```
var currentindex = $("#imageindex").val();
var totalimages = lights.length;

if( currentindex > totalimages ) {
    currentindex = 0;
}
image.src = lights[currentindex];

//New Index
var newindex = currentindex + 1;

//Set new index value
$("#imageindex").val(newindex);
```